# Jquery on selected dropdownlist item show a hidden div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I want to show a hidden div tag when i select a comparative question. My code for the drop down list is as follows :

```
    <%=Html.DropDownList("QuestionType", new List<SelectListItem>
                     {
                        new SelectListItem{Text="Standard", Value = "1"}, 
                        new SelectListItem{Text="Custom", Value = "2"},
                        new SelectListItem{Text="Demographic", Value = "3"},
                        new SelectListItem{Text="Ranking", Value = "4"},
                        new SelectListItem{Text="Comparative", Value = "5"}                                                                                    
                     }) %>
```

My code for my hidden div tag:

```
<!--Create Comparative Question Partial View-->
<div id="divCreateComparativeQuestion">
<% Html.RenderPartial("CreateComparativeQuestion"); %>
</div>
```

So when the user clicks on comparative question from the drop down list, I want to go something like

```
        $('#divCreateComparativeQuestion').show();
        $('#divCreateComparativeQuestion :input').removeAttr('disabled');
```

How would i go about achieving this? Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you've already got. Just hook into the `change` event of the dropdownlist.

```
$(function() {
   $('#yourdropdown').change(function() {
      $('#divCreateComparativeQuestion').show();
   });
});
```

No need to remove the disabled attribute - as that's what `show()` does anyway.